# How to find an element in an array of structs in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have to write a function that finds a product with given code from the given array. If product is found, a pointer to the corresponding array element is returned.

My main problem is that the given code should first be truncated to seven characters and only after that compared with array elements.

Would greatly appreciate your help.

```
struct product *find_product(struct product_array *pa, const char *code) 

{   
char *temp;
int i = 0;
    while (*code) {
        temp[i] = (*code);
        code++;
        i++;
        if (i == 7)
            break;
    }
    temp[i] = '\0';

for (int j = 0; j < pa->count; j++)
    if (pa->arr[j].code == temp[i])
        return &(pa->arr[j]);
}
```

Comment: First thing I noticed was `temp` is not initialized and you are using it which will lead to undefined behavior

Comment: You did not allocate any memory for `temp`.  Use `malloc`/`calloc` to do it. And what did you mean by "*given code should first be truncated to seven characters*"?

Comment: `if (pa->arr[j].code == temp[i])` is the same as `if (pa->arr[j].code == 0)`. Use `strcmp` or `strncmp` to compare two strings

Comment: You can use `strncpy()` to copy the first 7 characters of `code` to `temp`, you don't need to write your own loop.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you just use strncmp in a loop?

```
struct product *find_product(struct product_array *pa, const char *code) 
{ 
   for (size_t i = 0; i < pa->count; ++i)
   {
      if (strncmp(pa->arr[i].code, code, 7) == 0)
          return &pa->arr[i];
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`temp` is a pointer which is uninitialized and you are dereferencing it which will lead to undefined behavior.

```
temp = malloc(size); // Allocate some memory size = 8 in your case
```

One more mistake I see is

```
if (pa->arr[j].code == temp[i]) // i is already indexing `\0`
```

should be

```
strcmp(pa->arr[j].code,temp); // returns 0 if both the strings are same
```

This code can completely be avoided if you can use [strncmp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, you are using `temp` uninitialized and you are always comparing characters with `'\0'`.

You don't need a `temp` variable:

> int strncmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num );
>
> Compare characters of two strings
>
> Compares up to num characters of the
>   C string str1 to those of the C string str2.

```
/* Don't use magic numbers like 7 in the body of function */
#define PRODUCT_CODE_LEN 7

struct product *find_product(struct product_array *pa, const char *code) 
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < pa->count; i++) {
        if (strncmp(pa->arr[i].code, code, PRODUCT_CODE_LEN) == 0)
            return &(pa->arr[i]);
    }
    return NULL; /* Not found */
}
```

Comment: UB galore if the product is not to be found.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `char* temp;` you are just declaring an uninitialized pointer

In your case since you say that the code is truncated to 7 you could create a buffer
on the stack with place for the code

```
char temp[8];
```

Writing

```
temp[i] = (*code);
code++;
i++;
```

Can be simplified to:

```
temp[i++] = *code++;
```

In your loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < pa->count; j++)
    if (pa->arr[j].code == temp[i])
        return &(pa->arr[j]);
```

You are comparing the address of `code` and the character value of `temp[i]` which incidentally could be 8 and outside the array.

Instead what you want to do is compare what code *points to* and what temp *contains*:

```
for (int j = 0; j < pa->count; j++)
    if (!strncmp(pa->arr[j].code, temp, 7)
        return &(pa->arr[j]);
```

You should also `return NULL;` if nothing was found, seems you do not return anything.

Probably a good thing is also to make sure your temp[] always contains 7 characters.